# python to java string of substring

Tags: java, python, split

trying to convert this into Java from Python. How could I possible do it in one line?

```
for k in range(len(i[0])-len(i[1].split(" ")[-1])):
     # this part
     print(i[0][k:len(i[1].split(" ")[0])+k])
```

Comment: this question is getting downvoted (and will likely get closed) because you haven't explained what you've attempted so far. At the very least, you should explain what the loop is currently doing so people can suggest how to guide you. But SO isn't here to just solve your problems ourselves.

Comment: That's going to depend on what `i` is in the Java code. A `List`? An array? A `Pair` of some sort? Is `i[0]` a string?

Comment: sorry. i[0] is an element string in an array e.g "some text here"

Comment: So for example if your run this in python you with a string "some text here" the output should be :some 
ome t
me te
e tex
 text
text 
ext h
xt he
t her
 here
here
ere                                                                                                                                              Reason for that is I would like to check if a specific string matches with another one the only part messes up my code in java is that which I am not sure if that's possible

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int k = 0; k < updateCardHolderName.length()-fullCardHolderName[fullCardHolderName.length-1].length(); k++ ) {
    System.our.println(str1.substring(k,str2.lengthj+k));
}
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for probably did not describe it very well.